# Door handle stopped working after removing

Tags: door

So I started vinyl wrapping my car, two doors done. I removed the door handles to do the doors. My first door handle removal and wrap went perfect, nothing wrong with it. However, after removing my second door and putting it back together, pulling on the handle does not open the door. The torx screw is still in place, it didn't fall out. I can still screw it back onto the door handle, but the handle itself doesnt open when it's pulled. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Model/year of the car will help. Does you interior panel out? Could you see if the mechanism is working from the interior?

Comment: Pictures of door's internals too please.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing which vehicle this is for it will be difficult to provide specific help for your situation.

However, based on the description, there is a good chance the that the cable which attaches the interior door handle to the door lock actuator has not been reattached properly.